# How to test xslt variable with html tag against empty string?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Let's say, I have a xslt variable `$item`.  Up to the processing, `$item` may be equal to a HTML tag, for example: `<td><input style="width: 10em"></td>` or it may be an empty string.

Now I want to test if `$item` is empty or not. If I do `<xsl:if test="$item = ''">`, it seems that the condition turn out to be true if `$item = <td><input style="width: 10em"></td>`. How can I design a conditional test to see whether `$item` is truly empty or not?

Here is the sample code I want to make it to work. `$item` may contain `<td><input></td>` as the output and the if test pass in this case, whilst I don't want that. `$item` may contain nothing at all, since the template match nothing. Nothing here means no `<td><input></td>` or whatsoever.

```
<xsl:variable name="item">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:varialbe>

<xsl:if test="$item=''">
  <!-- do something here -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: So how do you bind a value to the variable `item`, how does your input data look? Why is the variable value an element node sometimes and an empty string otherwise? Are you sure it is not just simply an empty sequence in the latter case?

Comment: The `item` gets its value from a template rule processing. It may be empty (totally) because the template rule does not match anything at all. Or it may contain `<td><input></td>`, which is returned by the template rule processing.

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete samples of the variable binding and the possible inputs. It is still not clear whether you are not simply dealing with an empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
<xsl:variable name="item">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:variable>
```

the variable in XSLT 1 is a result tree fragment and in XSLT 2 and later a document (fragment) node populated with the result of the `apply-templates`.

You haven't shown any context in which you bind the variable but it will always be a document fragment node in XSLT 2, if you want to distinguish whether it contains any nodes or not you can use e.g. `if ($item/node()) then ... else ...`, the `then` expression will be used if the `$item` document fragment node has any child nodes (e.g. created by the apply-templates), then `else` expression if it contains no child nodes at all.

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 2.0+**

You can test whether $item is a zero length string using

```
$item instance of xs:string and $item eq ""
```

(though you may also want to accept instances of `xs:untypedAtomic`)

**XSLT 1.0**

It's a long time since I used 1.0 so I may have overlooked something; the only idea that occurs to me is

```
string($item) = "" and not($item)
```

Which relies on the fact that if `$item` is a node then its effective boolean value is `true`, even if its string value is empty. You might simply be able to use the condition `not($item)` on its own, though that might not give the right answer if, for example, `$item` is a number.

**PS:** Please tag XSLT questions to indicate which version of the language you are using; the answers will often be different.